# PHP version of Python Clint command-line tools?

Tags: php

Are there any PHP libraries that provide similar functionality to Kenneth Reitz's [clint](https://github.com/kennethreitz/Clint) library for Python, especially indents and colors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

https://github.com/maximebf/ConsoleKit

Answer (score 1):

The Symfony project contains a very nice [Console component](http://symfony.com/doc/master/components/console.html) which can be used standalone.

It is used in the micro framework [Cilex](https://github.com/Cilex/Cilex), which could be interesting to have a look at.